# mysql: Use LIMIT with LEFT JOIN and COUNT

Tags: mysql, database, join, count, limit

I have 3 tables:

- `productos` table:

  ```
  | id_producto | nombre_productos |
  | ----------- | ---------------- |
  | 1           | espinete t-shirt |
  | 2           | batman t-shirt   |
  | 3           | simpson t-shirt  |
  ```
- `usuarios` table:

  ```
   | id_usuario | nombre_usuario  |
   | ------- ---| --------------- |
   | 1          | jose perez      |
   | 2          | manolo garcia   |
   | 3          | antonio sanchez |
  ```
- `favoritos` table:

  ```
   | id_favorito | id_producto | id_usuario |
   | ----------- | ----------- | ---------- |
   | 1           | 3           | 2          |
   | 2           | 1           | 3          |
   | 3           | 2           | 1          |
  ```

Where a user (`usuario`) can add products (`productos`) as favorites (`favoritos`). I am interested in listing all the products with the number of times they have been added to favorites, ordering it by that quantity, and limiting the result to X products to later carry out the pagination of the products. I don't know how to use LIMIT correctly in this query:

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_favorito
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
```

If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it, greetings to all!

Answer (score 0):

Thisowulf give you ten most liked products

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_favorito
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

And
this number 10 to 20

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_favorito
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!!

I did some query to the database directly and it works fine.

I will try to adapt it to my project with php

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake when writing the query ...

I correct it. Also change the solution:

`ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_favorito`.

**The correct thing is to put the following:**

`ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_producto`

It would look like this:

```
SELECT productos.id_producto,
COUNT(favoritos.id_favorito) AS vecesAnyadido
FROM productos
LEFT JOIN favoritos 
ON productos.id_producto = favoritos.id_producto
GROUP BY productos.id_producto
ORDER BY vecesAnyadido DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;
```